# how to return data by checking if it exists in a table by using specific where clause

Tags: sql

I need to be able to check a column in a table -- let's call it inactive if it is "N" then return that value (easy enough)
the hard part.

I also need to check to see if a user is in another table depending on a year and then return that user whether the user has Inactive 'N' or 'Y'

So for example

Table #1:

```
userid  inactive  year           dept
-------------------------------------
1           N      2023           K
2           Y      2023           K
3           N      2023           K
4           Y      2023           K
```

Table #2

```
userid   someOtherID   
--------------------
2             6
```

In this example, I need to return everything with the 'N' and the one with the 'Y' because the Y exists in the 2nd table.

The `where` clause checks for the year and a dept, however here is the kicker:

if table 1 has a Y but it isn't in table 2, do not return that value

So in the above example, I would need to return ID's 1, 2, 3 but not 4

Here is a working example of the query I need to change:

```
SELECT
    p.id,              
    sp.Cohort,
    sp.programID,   
    sp.Inactive
FROM 
    dbo.people p
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Programs sp ON p.id = sp.id
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.type ctp ON sp.typeid = ctp.programid
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.address ppa ON p.id = ppa.id
WHERE 
    ctp.typeid = 'AType' 
    AND sp.Cohort = 2023
    -- AND sp.Inactive = 'N' <--this is where I'm stuck
ORDER BY
    p.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
p.id,              
sp.Cohort,
sp.programID,   
sp.Inactive
FROM dbo.people p
INNER JOIN dbo.Programs sp ON p.id= sp.id
INNER JOIN dbo.type ctp ON sp.typeid= ctp.programid
LEFT JOIN dbo.address ppa ON p.id= ppa.id
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON p.id = t2.userid  -- Join with table2, replace the name with real name of table2
WHERE ctp.typeid = 'AType' 
AND sp.Cohort = 2023
AND (sp.Inactive = 'N' OR (sp.Inactive = 'Y' AND t2.userid IS NOT NULL))  -- Check for 'N' or 'Y' with existence in table2
ORDER BY p.id
```

This should work for you.

Comment: thanks this gets me on the right track